# Convert array to another array filter Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this array

```
var setData =
[{"id":"1","name":"1","position":"1","office":"NY","active":"1"},
{"id":"2","name":"2","position":"2","office":"NY","active":"0"},
{"id":"3","name":"3","position":"3","office":"NY","active":"0"}
];
```

What i need isto get this new array with active fields 1

```
var activeData =
[{"id":"1","name":"1","position":"1","office":"NY","active":"1"}
];
```

Comment: Just loop over `setData` and see if the `active` field of each object is `1`.  If it is, push that object into the `activeData` array.

Comment: Nice can you post a answer?

Comment: @RocketHazmat There is a better way, check out T.J Crowder's answer and mine which is the same.

Comment: @Roger: That's basically what my solution does under the covers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh, yes. However the expression brings some advantages, like better expressed code which leads to more mantainability. Also possibly there is some room for optimization inside the filter function.

Answer (score 3):

You almost seem to know the answer: Use [`Array#filter`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20):

```
var filteredArray = setData.filter(function(entry) {
    return entry.active === "1";
});
```

It's an ES5 thing, but can be shimmed for older browsers. `filter` constructs a new array from each element for which your filter function returns a truthy value.

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter function of javascript.

```
var activeData = setData.filter(function (element) {
    return element.active === "1";
});
```

The filter function receives a function that takes an element of the array and makes a new array with the elements for which the function returns true (a predicate holds).

See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Edit:

A few more comments.

T. J. brings the "truthy" word here. What this means is that in javascript, not only true and false can be used in logic statements. A truthy value is every value that when put in an if else statement, the program flows through the "then" branch and a falsy value is the opposite. e.g.

```
if ({}) alert("Truthy"); else alsert("Falsy"); //Truthy
if ([]) alert("Truthy"); else alsert("Falsy"); //Truthy
if (1) alert("Truthy"); else alsert("Falsy"); //Truthy
if (true) alert("Truthy"); else alsert("Falsy"); //Truthy

if ("") alert("Truthy"); else alsert("Falsy"); //Falsy
if (0) alert("Truthy"); else alsert("Falsy"); //Falsy
if (false) alert("Truthy"); else alsert("Falsy"); //Falsy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

### jQuery [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
var activeData = [];

$.each(setData,function(i,v){
  if(v.active=="1") activeData.push(v);
});
```

Comment: Better use the grep function for a jQuery alternative?